# select only time from datetime field in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

In my table I have a datetime field that stores dates in this format:

```
YYYY/mm/dd HH:MM:SS
```

Now I need to retrieve via query only the time.

I have tried this

```
SELECT time(start_date)
FROM table
LIMIT 100
```

but no luck, it gives me "not an error" but no records return

Any idea?

**EDIT**

I solved it! The problem is that SQLite needs Times to be in a format in which if hours, minutes and seconds are less than 10 they must be represented with the zero.

For example:

```
          H:M:S
WRONG --> 12:1:30
RIGHT --> 12:01:30
```

Moreover, the correct format for dates is YYYY-mm-dd and not YYYY/mm/dd.

Answer (score 9):

There is a built-in function in SQLite called **strftime(format,datetime)** which can be used to get whatever piece of information you require from the given datetime. In your case you can use in this way:

```
SELECT strftime('%H:%M:%S',start_date) FROM table LIMIT 100;
```